# Abstract enum in c#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, enums, abstract

Is there a way to make a (`protected`) `enum` `abstract` in C#?
Example of base class:

```
protected abstract enum commands{}; //CS0106        
protected abstract void useCommands(commands meh);
```

This does not compile, since "`abstract` is not valid for this item".
Is there a working way to achive the desired behaviour?

Comment: What's the purpose of abstract enum?

Comment: Short of using strings to manage your states ... no.

Comment: `enum` is a keyword, use `Enum` as a class name

Comment: use static class with static string properties with only get method...

Comment: @pwas considering what I'm reading here: I cannot really tell anymore. The idea was that I'd have a safer way to implement my sub-classes, as they HAD to have an implementation of that enum.

Comment: @Mark `enum` cannot be a base type for anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. All enums must derive from `System.Enum`
2. All enums are value types and hence sealed.

Because of above these two rules, you *cannot inherit* enums.

Comment: The second one relly helps me get why this cannot work the way I thought.

Answer (score 10):

***enum*** is a *keyword*, not a *class name*:

```
  // MyCommand is a class name while 'enum' is a keyword
  public enum MyCommand {
    None,
    Something
  }
```

So your code should be

```
  // Enum (but not enum) is a class name: 
  // Enum is an abstract class for any enum (including MyCommand)
  protected abstract Enum commands {
    get;
  };
```

Possible abstract property implementation could be :

```
  protected override Enum commands {
    get { 
      return MyCommand.None;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

If I understand you, you are trying to make an abstract class which is somewhat similar to a State Machine. You have an `enum` storing commands which you want your derived classes to define.

This can be achieved by using a generic class and have your `enum` passed as the templated type.
Here's an example of how to achieve this.

```
public abstract baseClass <commandType>
{
    protected abstract void useCommands (commandType meh);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This can be later derived to be used as follows:

```
public enum commands {stop, wait, go};

public class derivedClass : baseClass <commands>
{
    protected override void useCommands (commands meh)
    {
         .
         .
         .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  An `enum` is an `enum`, not a `class`.  Only a `class` can be `abstract` because only a `class` can be inherited.  The point of being abstract is to provide a common base that will be inherited by other types.  An `enum` doesn't inherit anything so how could an `abstract` `enum` be implemented or extended?

Comment: "enum is an enum"? enum is a value type

Comment: Not only classes can be inherited. Fields, methods and properties as well, all of those as `abstract` as well.

Comment: @Juan, so you're implying that an `enum` is not an `enum`?  Is, for instance, `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult` not an `enum`?

Comment: @Mark, fields, methods and properties are not types.  When creating a derived type, that type can only be derived from a `class`.  You can't create a type that is derived from a field, method or property.  When you inherit a class of course you inherit its members but that's not the same thing.

Comment: I certainly can see how an enum could be "extended". If two enums share a common subset of their values, then the common range could arguably be called a sub type. It would simply be a matter of avoiding duplication in type definition. I see many pitfalls and not many gains.

Comment: @Tormod, that would only be in the developer's head.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The value types consist of two main categories: structs and enumerations. Unlike with reference types, you cannot derive a new type from a value type. However, like reference types, structs can implement interfaces. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx Saying "enum is an enum" is like saying "quantum physics is quantum physics". Just show a little more effort in the answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What would be in my head? Tormod pretty much gets what I had in mind, though with all the complications this causes (as taken from this thread) I do doubt the benefit of not having to duplicate certain enum-members, vs. twisting my brain to make a clean implementation.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It could be a language feature without having any IL implication, certainly. I do not understand what you mean by "in the developers head". Avoiding duplication is certainly focus for most programming languages.

Comment: @Juan, so the rest of the words in my answer appeared without any effort on my part? Impressive!